# Cross domain javascript ajax request - status 200 OK but no response

Tags: ajax

Here is my situation:
Im creating a widget that site admins can embed in their site and the data are stored in my server. So the script basically has to make an ajax request to a php file in my server to update the database. Right? Right :)
The ajax request **works excellent** when i run it in my **local server** but it does *not work* when the php file is on my *ONLINE* server.
This is the code im using:

```
var url = "http://www.mydomain.net/ajax_php.php";
var params = "com=ins&id=1&mail=mymail@site.net";
http.async = true;
http.open("POST", url, true);       

http.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

    //do my things here
    alert( http.responseText ); 

    }
}
http.send(params);
```

In firebug it shows: http://www.mydomain.net/ajax_php.php 200 OK X 600ms.

When i check the ajax responnseText I always get a Status:0

Now my question is: "Can i do cross-domain ajax requests by default? Might this be a cross-domain ajax problem? Since it works when the requested file resides in my local server but DOESN'T work when the requested file is in another server, im thinking ajax requests to another remote server might be denied? Can you help me clear on this?
Thanks..

Comment: You may want to upvote and/or accept the answer or answers that helped you out.  It will increase your rep a little and also your answer acceptance percentage, which helps later as you ask more questions.  (A higher percentage will attract more people to answer questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-domain requests are not directly allowed.  However, there is a commonly-used technique called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) that will allow you to avoid this restriction through the use of script tags.  Basically, you create a callback function with a known name:

```
function receiveData(data) {
    // ...
}
```

And then your server wraps JSON data in a function call, like this:

```
receiveData({"the": "data"});
```

And you "call" the cross-domain server by adding a `script` tag to your page.  jQuery elegantly wraps all of this up in its `ajax` function.

Another technique that I've had to use at times is cross-document communication through iframes.  You can have one window talk to another, even cross-domain, in a restricted manner through [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).  Note that only recent browsers have this functionality, so that option is not viable in all cases without resorting to hackery.

Comment: God! This was the fastest reply ever :) Thanks for clarifying Jacob.
I will try to understand how JSONP works and I may return to ask here if i need further help...
Such a great community :)

Comment: I Googled and found this example which was super easy to understand http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/ 
Is this exactly what you meant @Jacob ?

Comment: Yep. Glad you found something easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to have your response sent back to your client via a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) call.

What you'll need to do is to have your request for data wrapped in a script tag.  Your server will respond with your data wrapped in a function call.  By downloading the script as an external resource, your browser will execute the script (just like adding a reference to an external JS file like jQuery) and pass the data to a known JS method.  Your JS method will then take the data and do whatever you need to do with it.

Lots of steps involved.  Using a library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) provides a lot of support for this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @David
I know that jQuery is easier but my widget has to be embeded in other sites which may or may not have jQuery loaded. I didnt want to load jQuery dynamically but i chose "plain" javascript to do the job faster. I think i found the example needed, i posted it here in comments :)

Comment: @Albo - understood.  I was just mentioning the framework; didn't mean to imply that you should use it.  I think it's great you're doing it sans framework - definitely make you understand what's going on.  Many people just think they can use jQuery, add a `jsonp` data type, and everything "just works".  Definitely not the case.